# Proper way to save multiple checkboxes to MySQL (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, database-optimization

Using Laravel 5.3 and MySQL 5.7.19.

I want to save bunch of options (true/false) to my `User` model.

These will be used to determine whether certain notifications will be sent to user or not. I will never need to filter `Users` by these flags. There is a possibility that new flags will be introduced but I don't think the number of flags should ever go above 20-50.

**1.** My first idea is to save each of the options as separate `tinyint(1)` column but it will look really, really ugly, even if I prefix these with something like `notification_flags_`.

**2.** Second idea is to save the values as integer column and use bitwise operations to deduce the property using PHP. This will take slightly more time to implement but it will look cleaner. Not sure about the performance but probably slower than method 1.

**3.** Third option is to use another table for flags (let's call this `NotficationFlag` model) and connect each `User` to this table via pivot table (using Laravel's manyToMany helper/method (not sure of the proper name)). This option would give me most flexibility (which I don't really need given the nature of the problem) and I think it would be the slowest, but I don't really know.

**4.** Fourth option would be to have oneToOne relation with `NotificationFlag` model and in this model to have a column for each flag. This seems to me as the same as option one but a bit nicer, and a bit slower.

What is the best way to do this? It seems to me that first option is the best but something inside me is telling me there must be a nicer way. Is there?

Comment: This seems kind of opinion-based, but I'd go with Option 3. I would prioritize ease of maintenance and usability over performance unless performance becomes a problem. It will be easier to denormalize than vice-versa.

Comment: Two tables in a 1:1 relationship is _usually_ a bad design.  I think that all 4 options will involve a full table scan (or worse).  The most compact would be a `BIGINT UNSIGNED` (your #2) or `SET` -- this would pack up to 64 flags into 8 bytes, maybe less.